# XSLT - nested foreach Excel provides no output

Tags: excel, xslt

I am attempting to pull out some values and display an array of arrays in Excel dynamically. However, my nested for-each doesn't and I receive no output no matter what I try. I have, of course, left out some stuff within the `sheet` and `data`, so right now they seem as if they're unnecessarily nested, but that isn't the case.

XML:

```xml
<report>
  <sheet>
    <data>
      <table>
        <row>
          <column value="Germany" />
          <column value="Berlin" />
          <column value="2321341" />
        </row>
        <row>
          <column value="USA" />
          <column value="Washington DC" />
          <column value="11111" />
        </row>
      </table>
    </data>
  </sheet>
</report>
```

The XSL nested for-each I try to get to work. It works when I remove the inner for-each and try displaying the first value by doing `<xsl:value-of select="column/@value">`, so it creates two new rows, each containing the name of the country (which is the first element of the column list).

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="report/sheet/data/table/row">
<ss:Row>
    <xsl:for-each select="row/columm">
    <ss:Cell>
        <ss:Data ss:Type="String">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        </ss:Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ss:Row>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a typo in:

```
<xsl:for-each select="row/columm">
```

The name of the element is `column`, not `columm`.

---

More importantly, the instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="report/sheet/data/table/row">
```

puts you in the context of `row`. From this context,

```
<xsl:for-each select="row/column">
```

selects nothing, because `row` is not a child of itself. It needs to be:

```
<xsl:for-each select="column">
```